# missing dependencies in downloaded project

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use project https://github.com/castor-software/decompilercmp. I downloaded from git, noticed it's a maven project, installed maven, then tried to do:

```
mvn install
```

and got:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for se.kth:decompiler-cmp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for scala:jardiff:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/jardiff.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 34, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for jd:jd-core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/jd-core-1.0.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 42, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for jadx:jadx-cli:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/jadx-0.9.0/lib/jadx-cli-0.9.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 50, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for cli.jd:jd-gui:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/jd-gui-1.4.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 58, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.jode:jode-decompiler:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/jode-1.1.2-pre1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 65, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: fr.inria.gforge.spoon:spoon-core:jar -> version 7.3.0 vs 7.5.0 @ line 163, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for scala:jardiff:jar refers to a non-existing file /Users/shlomiagiv/work/decompilercmp/lib/jardiff.jar @ line 34, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for jd:jd-core:jar refers to a non-existing file /Users/shlomiagiv/work/decompilercmp/lib/jd-core-1.0.0.jar @ line 42, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for jadx:jadx-cli:jar refers to a non-existing file /Users/shlomiagiv/work/decompilercmp/lib/jadx-0.9.0/lib/jadx-cli-0.9.0.jar @ line 50, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for cli.jd:jd-gui:jar refers to a non-existing file /Users/shlomiagiv/work/decompilercmp/lib/jd-gui-1.4.1.jar @ line 58, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.jode:jode-decompiler:jar refers to a non-existing file /Users/shlomiagiv/work/decompilercmp/lib/jode-1.1.2-pre1.jar @ line 65, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< se.kth:decompiler-cmp >------------------------
[INFO] Building decompiler-cmp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.483 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-03T08:13:12+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project decompiler-cmp: Could not resolve dependencies for project se.kth:decompiler-cmp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: scala:jardiff:jar:1.2.0, jd:jd-core:jar:1.0.0, jadx:jadx-cli:jar:0.9.0, cli.jd:jd-gui:jar:1.4.1, org.jode:jode-decompiler:jar:1.2.1-pre1: Could not find artifact scala:jardiff:jar:1.2.0 at specified path /Users/shlomiagiv/work/decompilercmp/lib/jardiff.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR]
```

[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

those missing dependencies are various decompilers the project is trying to reach.
How do I get/point to them? Note that I'm using MacOS

example pom.xml entry for jadx:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>jadx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jadx-cli</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jadx-0.9.0/lib/jadx-cli-0.9.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, maven uses the concept of remote repostories (like [maven central](https://search.maven.org/)) to look up the dependencies of your project and store them in local repository cache (~/.m2 by default). 
You can add your own remote repositories if you want.

If you define a dependency in the system scope however, this means that you instruct maven that the jar is not in a repository and instead its up to *you* to provide it in the folder that *you* specify (`systemPath`). This method effectively bypasses the maven dependency resolution mechanism and in general should not be used for real projects. Instead one should install special products like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) that serve as a remote proxy and can host your own JARs as well.

*Why should system scope be used at all?*

Usually it shouldn't, consider using it only if you have jars that cannot be published to remote repository (your private company's commercial artifacts) and you don't have a nexus/artifactory and don't want to install it (if you're 1 developer that runs stuff on your local machine or something)

If you decide to use the system scope anyway, you're by yourself responsible for "providing" these dependencies to maven, so you should probably find these artifacts by yourself. Once you know where the jars, you can copy them to the folder specified in the `systemPath` and keep bypassing maven's dependency resolution mechanism.

Another (arguably somewhat better approach) is to stop using system scope at all and once you've found the jars, use mvn install:install-file command to install the file to the local repository cache (~/.m2). You'll be able to specify group id, artifact id, version, and it will store this jar in the correct place. Then you'll be able to refer this jar as a regular maven dependency.

This [Link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) is for tutorial that shows how to work with these "3rd party" jars.

Comment: my 3rd party libs don't contain any pom.xml, and contain lots of jars.
for instance, https://github.com/skylot/jadx
What do I do then?

Comment: using system scope doesn't require pom, only a "ready" jar (doesn't matter how was it build). If you use install:install-file - it will generate a pom for you right in the ~/.m2/repository/<group-that-you-specify>/<artifact-that-you-specify>/<version-that-you-specify>

Comment: BTW, the link that you've provided uses Gradle, another build system. It can be integrated with maven local repositories, look here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-maven-local-repository-for-gradle-build/2244

Comment: 1. install gradle. 2. edit gradle build file and add `repositories {
  mavenLocal()`
} 3. run: `gradle build`. 4. locate the artifacts in the maven repository (~/.m2). 5. In your pom update the dependencies (remove system scope and use groupId/artifact Id that under which gradle built the thirdparty stuff). 6. run `mvn install` - should work